# mdframed gives a blank pages

Tags: mdframed

Good time of the day!
After I use  mdframed in the following example, there is no text after use

```
   \begin{mdframed}
   \tableofcontents
   \end{mdframed}
```

, no TOC, not chapter heading, and no text "ddddd".

Here is the entire file:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false,14pt,titlepage]{scrreprt}


%\pagenumbering{roman}

\usepackage{ucs}   %  unicode support
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

% \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\date{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{)\arabic{enumi}(}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii}(}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=1cm,labelindent=0.5cm }
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0.5cm,labelindent=1cm }

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\oneline}{

\begin{itemize}
\setstretch{1.5}{
\item[]
\rule[0 cm]{16cm}{0.4pt}

 }
\end{itemize}
}

\usepackage[left= 1cm, right= 1.5 cm, top=1cm,bottom=1cm, footskip=0.5cm]{geometry}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small} 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{{\tiny}}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{5pt}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{sltables}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}

%\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

%--------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}



\begin{titlepage}

\vspace*{0.2 cm}

\begin{center}


{\huge  בדיקת דירה \par}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}


\mdfsetup{   roundcorner=20pt}

   \begin{mdframed}
   \tableofcontents
   \end{mdframed}

%\begin{framed}
%\vspace*{-1.2 cm}
%\tableofcontents
%\end{framed}


\section{תוכנית כללית}

ddddd


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
\L{
\begin{mdframed} [roundcorner=10pt]
\vspace*{-1.5 cm}
\R{\tableofcontents}
\end{mdframed}
}
```

Comment: Please use allways a complete MWE to make it easy to see if it compiles and does what is wanted. And please explain the code. Not all readers here know `\vspace` or `\R` or ...